# Create user in SQL Anywhere

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to create user/groups with sql-Sybase:

```
CREATE USER type IDENTIFIED BY pass;
```

but the name of the user come for by through the data in the database, as well as the password.

It is still necessary to define what actions may have in the database. Example, the Auditor can only select all the tables presented in this DB.

[image: My Database]

Comment: Are you working with Sybase or SQL Server.  The commands will vary based on which product you are working

Comment: Ok, Sybase was a company, not a database.  They produced a number of different database management systems, includeding Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ and SQL anywhere.  The syntax for those products is different, so it's also helpful to know what product and version you are using.

Comment: It's for SQL Anywhere 12 v12.0.1.4134